# Fix Leaflet not including picture on a generated map

Tags: php, html, leaflet

I am using leaflet to create a map with a picture on it. The picture is generated from gda2tiles.py from a .tif file. The picture is currently generated successfully and it can be viewed when I open the link generated. The problem that I am having is that the map being created does not include the picture. There is a select box with the option to display or not the picture and it has the correct picture information, but the actual picture is not being added.

There are no error/warnings messages.

generate.php

```
<?php
require_once("SetFilePath.php");
require_once("CommonFunctions.php");
require_once("SetDBConnection.php");

$pageID = $_GET["pageid"];
$groups = $_REQUEST["groups"];
$projectID = $_GET["project"];
$pageTitle = $_GET["name"];
$center = $_GET["center"];
$zoom = $_GET["zoom"];
$minZoom = $_GET["minZoom"];
$maxZoom = $_GET["maxZoom"];

$con = SetDBConnection();

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to database server: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $deleteSQL =  "delete from visualization_project where id = $pageID";
    mysqli_query($con,$deleteSQL);

    $sql =  "select imagery_product.*, flight.Date as Date, product_type.Type as producttype ".
        "from imagery_product, flight, product_type ".
        "where flight.Project = $projectID and imagery_product.Flight = flight.ID ".
        "and imagery_product.Type = product_type.ID and imagery_product.Status = 'Finished' ".
        "order by Filename";

    $folderPath = SetTempFolderLocalPath().FormatFileName($pageTitle);
    if(!file_exists($folderPath)){
        if (!mkdir($folderPath, 0777, true)) {
            die('Failed to create folders...');
        }
    }

    $pagepath = $folderPath."/index.html";
    $viewPath = str_replace("/var/www/html/wordpress/","http://test.org/",$pagepath);

    $addSQL =   "insert into visualization_project (Name, Project, Path) ".
        "values ('$pageTitle', $projectID, '$viewPath')";
    mysqli_query($con,$addSQL);
    $vProjectID = $con->insert_id;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $productList = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $productList[] = $row;
    }
    $zIndex = 50;

    $layerText = "";
    $overLayerText = "";

    $firstLayer = true;

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $idList = preg_split("@;@", $group["IDs"], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if (count($idList) > 0){

            $addSQL =   "insert into visualization_group (Name, Type, Project) ".
                "values ('".$group["GroupName"]."', '". $group["Type"] ."',$vProjectID)";
            mysqli_query($con,$addSQL);
            $vGroupID = $con->insert_id;

            $groupText =    "{\n".
                "\tgroup: '".$group["GroupName"]."',\n".
                "\tlayers: [\n";

            foreach ($idList as $id){
                foreach ($productList as $product){
                    if($product["ID"] == $id){

                        $addSQL =   "insert into visualization_layer (Layer, GroupID) ".
                            "values ($id, $vGroupID)";
                        mysqli_query($con,$addSQL);

                        $boundaryText = "";

                        if ($product["Boundary"] != ""){
                            $bounds = explode(";", $product["Boundary"]);
                            $boundaryText = ", bounds: L.latLngBounds([";
                            foreach ($bounds as $bound){
                                $point = "L.latLng(".$bound."),";
                                $boundaryText .= $point;
                            }


                            $boundaryText = rtrim($boundaryText,",")."])";
                        }

                        if ($product["producttype"] == "V") {
                            $base_json_name = str_ireplace(".geojson","",$product["FileName"]);
                            $layerName = "layer_".$base_json_name;
                            $paneName  =  "pane_".$base_json_name;

                            $layer1 = "map.createPane('".$paneName."'); \n";
                            $layer2 = "map.getPane('".$paneName."').style.zIndex = ".$zIndex."; \n";
                            $layer3 = "map.getPane('".$paneName."').style.pointerEvents = 'none'; \n";
                            $layer4 = "var ".$layerName." = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('".$product["UploadFolder"]."/".$product["FileName"]."', {pane: '".$paneName."'}); \n";

                            $layer = $layer1.$layer2.$layer3.$layer4;

                        } else {

                            $layerName = "layer_".str_ireplace(".tif","",$product["FileName"]);
                            $layer =    "var ".$layerName." = L.tileLayer('".$product["TMSPath"].
                                "', {tms: true, zIndex: ".$zIndex.$boundaryText."}); \n";

                        }

                        $layerText .= $layer;

                        if ($firstLayer){
                            $activeText = "active: 'true',\n";
                            $firstLayer = false;
                        } else {
                            $activeText = "";
                        }

                        $groupText .=   "\t\t{\n".
                            "\t\t\tname: '".str_replace("-","/",$product["Date"])."',\n".
                            $activeText.
                            "\t\t\tlayer: ".$layerName."\n".
                            "\t\t},\n";

                        $zIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            $groupText .=       "\t]\n".
                "},\n";

            $overLayerText.= $groupText;
        }
    }

    $templatePath = getcwd()."/page_template.html";
    $pageContent = file_get_contents($templatePath);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#PAGE-TITLE#",$pageTitle, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#PROJECT-CENTER#",$center, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#DEFAULT-ZOOM#",$zoom, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#MIN-ZOOM#",$minZoom, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#MAX-ZOOM#",$maxZoom, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#LAYERS#",$layerText, $pageContent);
    $pageContent = str_replace("#OVER-LAYERS#",$overLayerText, $pageContent);

    echo $pageContent;

    $file = fopen($pagepath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, $pageContent);
    fclose($file);

    echo $viewPath;
}
?>
```

File generated

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>test4bigfile</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/leaflet-panel-layers.css" />

<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<br />
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="/js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="/js/leaflet-panel-layers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/leaflet-ajax/dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/js/legend.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/legend.css" />

<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-74689450-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: L.latLng([27.7823,-97.5606]),
        zoom: 19,
        minZoom: 17,
        maxZoom: 25,
        attributionControl: false
    });

    var osm_map = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        zIndex: 0
    });

    var mapbox = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Imagery from <a href="https://mapbox.com/about/maps/">MapBox</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        id: 'mapbox.satellite',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtZG9yaSIsImEiOiJjaWZmZzBwbjI4ZGdqc21seDFhOHA5dGcxIn0.4An46DNTDt97W992MRRWoQ',
        maxNativeZoom: 19,
        zIndex: 0
    });


    // Layers
    var layer_bigfgiletest4 = L.tileLayer('http://test.org/uas_data/uploads/products/test4/Inspire_2/MS/11-10-2020/tesflight4/RGB_Ortho/bigfgiletest4/Display/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true, zIndex: 50, bounds: L.latLngBounds([L.latLng(30.534394444444,-96.447652777778),L.latLng(30.534305555556,-96.443116666667),L.latLng(30.530427777778,-96.443216666667),L.latLng(30.530516666667,-96.447755555556),L.latLng(30.534394444444,-96.447652777778)])}); 

    
    
    map.addLayer(mapbox);

    var baseLayers = [
        {
            name: "Open Street Map",
            layer: osm_map
        },
        {
            name: "Satellie Map",
            layer: mapbox
        },
    ];

    var overLayers = [
        {
    group: 'test4',
    layers: [
        {
            name: '11/10/2020',
active: 'true',
            layer: layer_bigfgiletest4
        },
    ]
},

    ];

    var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers, overLayers, {collapsibleGroups: true});
    map.addControl(panelLayers);
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `layer_bigfgiletest4.addTo(map)` ?

Comment: I added it before var panelLayers = new L.Control... and it didn't work

Comment: No errors/warnings on the network tab of your browser's developer tools? Do the tile URLs match those of existing tiles? Do they look like the same tile URLs as in the autogenerated gdal2tiles demo webpage?

Comment: Yes, I believe I checked all of it. The problem is ```center: L.latLng([27.7823,-97.5606]), // way off layer bounds```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to visualize a high resolution picture covering a quite small area, given the bounds of your custom Tile Layer:

```js
var layer_bigfgiletest4 = L.tileLayer('<url>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  bounds: L.latLngBounds([
    L.latLng(30.534394444444, -96.447652777778),
    L.latLng(30.534305555556, -96.443116666667),
    L.latLng(30.530427777778, -96.443216666667),
    L.latLng(30.530516666667, -96.447755555556),
    L.latLng(30.534394444444, -96.447652777778)
  ])
});
```

But because your initial map view position is way off and already highly zoomed in, you may not be able to see it even after panning around quite a bit.

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: L.latLng([27.7823,-97.5606]), // way off layer bounds
        zoom: 19, // highly zoomed in
        minZoom: 17,
        maxZoom: 25
});
```

You can re-adjust your map position when your Layer is added:

```js
map.on("layeradd", function (event) {
  if (event.target === layer_bigfgiletest4) {
    map.fitBounds(/* same bounds */);
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems you are on the right track @ghybs, I hardcoded center: L.latLng([30.534394444444, -96.447652777778]) and the image is shown there. I am sorry I am a novice on leaflet. How would you implement your example and where?
This is what I tried near the end of the html page:

```map.on("layeradd", function (event) {
  if (event.target === layer_bigfgiletest4) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});```